# Meteor: How does javascript choose parameters add to function

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm making a Meteor application. In this application, I make a form allow for user to submit data. Firstly javascript is:

```
Template.post_question_form.events({
    'submit form' : function() {
        console.log("form submitted");
    }
});
```

After that, as tutorial. I add event parameter:

```
Template.post_question_form.events({
    'submit form' : function(event) {
        console.log("form submitted");
    }
});
```

Everything runs as I expected. the problem I don't know is: I'm come from Java world (strongly type language world), so I don't know how Javascript solve this. when your function's parameter is empty, javascript will called it. when your function's parameter is event, javascript will attach event object into this automatically. so how does javascript do in this case:

```
Template.post_question_form.events({
    'submit form' : function(param1, param2, param3, param4) {
        console.log("form submitted");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when your function's parameter is empty, javascript will called it. when your function's parameter is event, javascript will attach event object into this automatically. so how does javascript do in this case

It doesn't: Whatever's *calling* your function always passes it the event object. But in JavaScript, unlike Java, you can call a function with more, or fewer, arguments than it declares. Example:

```js
function takesNoArguments() {
  snippet.log("takesNoArguments");
}
function takesOneArgument(one) {
  snippet.log("takesOneArgument: one = " + one);
}

takesNoArguments();      // Call it with no args
takesNoArguments('foo'); // Call it with an arg

takesOneArgument();      // Call it with no args
takesOneArgument('foo'); // Call it with an arg
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

That outputs:

```
takesNoArguments
takesNoArguments
takesOneArgument: one = undefined
takesOneArgument: one = foo
```

If you call a JavaScript function with more arguments than it declares, that's fine (and the function can actually get at them, more on that below). If you call a JavaScript function with *fewer* arguments than it declares, that's also fine; the declared arguments you don't pass it get the value `undefined`.

So how can a function get access to the extra arguments you passed it if it doesn't declare them? Via the magic pseudo-array `arguments`. Let's modify our snippet above slightly:

```js
function takesNoArguments() {
  snippet.log("takesNoArguments: arguments.length = " + arguments.length + ", arguments[0] = " + arguments[0]);
}
function takesOneArgument(one) {
  snippet.log("takesOneArgument: one = " + one + ", arguments.length = " + arguments.length + ", arguments[0] = " + arguments[0]);
}

takesNoArguments();      // Call it with no args
takesNoArguments('foo'); // Call it with an arg

takesOneArgument();      // Call it with no args
takesOneArgument('foo'); // Call it with an arg
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

That outputs:

```
takesNoArguments: arguments.length = 0, arguments[0] = undefined
takesNoArguments: arguments.length = 1, arguments[0] = foo
takesOneArgument: one = undefined, arguments.length = 0, arguments[0] = undefined
takesOneArgument: one = foo, arguments.length = 1, arguments[0] = foo
```